# Como incluir um coluna com checkbox para todas as linhas no DataTable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Gostaria de colocar uma coluna no final, com um checkbox ou toggle switch button para todas as linhas vindas de uma chamada ajax.

Consegui colocar por sDefaultContext e mRender, mas o checkbox não funciona, não reconhece o click.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Atualmente, utilizo o seguinte trecho de código:

```
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
            //adiciona a classe para todas as células referente a coluna indicada
            {"sClass" : "hidden-xs sorting","aTargets" : [1]},
            {"mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' name=''></input>","aTargets": [3]}
        ]
```

Comment: Como você está adicionando os checkbox? você pode colocar assim na hora de adicionar o checkbox { onclick='Metodo()'; }

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Atualmente utilizo este trecho de código : oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
   "aoColumnDefs" : [
    //adiciona a classe para todas as células referente a coluna indicada
    {"sClass" : "hidden-xs sorting","aTargets" : [1]},
    {"mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' name=''></input>","aTargets": [3]}
   ], 

Ele aparece como eu quero só não funciona adequadamente

Comment: Faça assim -> oTable = $('#table1').dataTable({ "aoColumnDefs" : [ 
{"sClass" : "hidden-xs sorting","aTargets" : [1]}, {"mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<input onclick="alert('Chamar um método aqui');" type='checkbox' name=''></input>","aTargets": [3]} ], Basta colocar o método fora e criar... não tenta dar bind em elementos adicionados dinamicamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Faça assim

```
function MeuMetodo(){
alert('Faça o que quer aqui');
}

 "aoColumnDefs" : [
            //adiciona a classe para todas as células referente a coluna indicada
            {"sClass" : "hidden-xs sorting","aTargets" : [1]},
            {"mData": null, "sDefaultContent": "<input onclick='MeuMetodo();' type='checkbox' name=''></input>","aTargets": [3]}
        ]
```

Não é possível dar Bind do Jquery em elementos adicionados dinamicamente, a menos que a leitura do código que faz o Bind seja feita após adicionar o elemento HTML.

Comment: Obrigada! Funcionou! E para estilizar esse checkbox? Na verdade o que preciso é utilizar esse plug-in http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ , que transforma o checkbox em switch toggle button, mas parece que ele não reconhece o css e nem o js

Comment: Coloca class no input -> <input class="MeuInput" onclick='MeuMetodo();' type='checkbox' name=''></input> E rode o código do plugin $(".MeuInput").bootstrapSwitch();

Comment: não funcionou. Estava fazendo isso mas através do name

Comment: Tenta com class.. e roda o código APÓS o código de adicionar os checkbox.

Comment: Obrigada! Está funcionando!

Comment: Tenho mais um probleminha, não sei se você pode me ajudar, eu consegui gerar os botões e tudo, mas quando faço uma ação em um dos switches ele altera todos, devido ao sDefaultContent replicar para todas as linhas, e se eu colocar um ID no mesmo, não vai mudar pois o resto vai possuir o mesmo ID. Sabe o que eu posso fazer?